# Bootstrap JavaScript breaks ASP.NET postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, kentico

Seems like registering bootstrap.js to my page prevents all of my server controls, e.g. `asp:LinkButtons` and `asp:Buttons`, from triggering a postback.

I have the following C# script in my masterpage.  It just registers jQuery 1.11.1 and Bootstrap.js if the user isn't in Design mode in Kentico.  Otherwise it just loads jQuery 1.7.1.

If I don't include bootstrap.js, postbacks from my `asp:LinkButtons` and `asp:Buttons` occur as normal.  Otherwise, there's just no action happening at all.  Any ideas what could be happening?

I don't see any console errors in the browser, and I'm absolutely certain that including Bootstrap.js is somehow partially responsible for this behavior, if not entirely.  Everything works just find if it's not included (well, besides bootstrap jQuery modules of course).

```
<script runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Check for null document
    if(CMSContext.CurrentDocument != null)
    {
      if(CMS.PortalEngine.PortalContext.ViewMode.ToString() == "Design")
      {
        CMS.GlobalHelper.ScriptHelper.RegisterJQuery(this.Page);
      }
      else
      {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"jquery","<script src=\"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js\"><" + "/script>",false);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"bootstrap","<script src=\"/getmedia/453e9ad5-e05c-4fb2-b134-4d9cbd00c917/bootstrap-min.aspx\"><" + "/script>",false);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

> That bootstrap.min.js file is just the default bootstrap.min.js file for v3.3.2

**CODE IN-FRONT**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="IssuesSettings.ascx.cs" Inherits="CustomCode_Dashboard_Issues_Issues" %>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="gap"></div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ButtonCompletedProjects" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" OnClick="ButtonCompletedProjectsClicked">Show Completed Projects</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ButtonClosedIssues" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" OnClick="ButtonClosedIssuesClicked">Show Closed Issues</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
public partial class CustomCode_Dashboard_Issues_Issues : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // cookie name constants
    private const string CookieClosedIssuesName = "Dashboard-Issues-ShowClosedIssues";
    private const string CookieCompletedProjectsName = "Dashboard-Issues-ShowCompletedProjects";

    // boolean switches

    private bool _showClosedIssues;
    private bool _showCompletedProjects;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetShowClosedIssues();
        SetShowCompletedProjects();
        SetButtonStyles();
    }

    private void SetButtonStyles()
    {
        if (_showClosedIssues)
        {
            ButtonClosedIssues.CssClass += " active";
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonClosedIssues.CssClass += " inactive";
        }

        if (_showCompletedProjects)
        {
            ButtonCompletedProjects.CssClass += " active";
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonCompletedProjects.CssClass += " inactive";
        }
    }

    private void SetShowCompletedProjects()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[CookieCompletedProjectsName] != null)
        {
            _showCompletedProjects = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Cookies[CookieCompletedProjectsName].Value);
        }
        else
        {
            _showCompletedProjects = false;
        }
    }

    private void SetShowClosedIssues()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[CookieClosedIssuesName] != null)
        {
            _showClosedIssues = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Cookies[CookieClosedIssuesName].Value);
        }
        else
        {
            _showClosedIssues = false;
        }
    }

    protected void CLICKER(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("stuff");
    }

    protected void ButtonClosedIssuesClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("TEST");
        // if we're turning this off
        if (_showClosedIssues)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[CookieClosedIssuesName];

            cookie.Name = CookieClosedIssuesName;
            cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
            cookie.Value = "False";

            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        }
        // if we're turning this on
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie;

            if (Request.Cookies[CookieClosedIssuesName] != null)
            {
                cookie = Request.Cookies[CookieClosedIssuesName];

                cookie.Name = CookieClosedIssuesName;
                cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
                cookie.Value = "True";

                Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
            }
            else
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieClosedIssuesName);

                cookie.Name = CookieClosedIssuesName;
                cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
                cookie.Value = "True";

                Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
            }
        }

        Response.Redirect(CMSContext.CurrentDocument.AbsoluteURL);
    }

    protected void ButtonCompletedProjectsClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if we're turning this off
        if (_showCompletedProjects)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[CookieCompletedProjectsName];

            cookie.Name = CookieCompletedProjectsName;
            cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
            cookie.Value = "False";

            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            // change style of button
            ButtonCompletedProjects.CssClass.Replace("active","inactive");
        }
        // if we're turning this on
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie;

            if (Request.Cookies[CookieCompletedProjectsName] != null)
            {
                cookie = Request.Cookies[CookieCompletedProjectsName];

                cookie.Name = CookieCompletedProjectsName;
                cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
                cookie.Value = "True";

                Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

                ButtonCompletedProjects.CssClass.Replace("inactive", "active");
            }
            else
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieCompletedProjectsName);

                cookie.Name = CookieCompletedProjectsName;
                cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
                cookie.Value = "True";

                Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            }
        }

        Response.Redirect(CMSContext.CurrentDocument.AbsoluteURL);
    }



}
```

Comment: Hey @Jerreck, have you tried to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead of `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`? I'm not sure, but this might work! Hope it helps!

Comment: The main difference between scriptblock and startupscript is that the first one appears in the beginning of the HTML output and the other one goes just before the form's closing tag. In case of registering libraries it hardly matters. What I would try is putting a JS breakpoint into `function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {...}`. You'll see whether it gets hit or not and perhaps you can step through the code and find where it dies. Also, run your code through an HTML validator just to see that the markup is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the button.js plugin calls `preventDefault()` on an element with the `data-toggle="buttons"` data attribute, and the `<asp:LinkButton>` server control places its '_doPostBack' function call within the `href=""` attribute of the anchor tag it renders.  Therefore the button.js plugin prevents the postback from happening.

I just copy/pasted the markup from the bootstrap docs so I happened to have that attribute on my `<div class="btn-group">`:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ButtonCompletedProjects" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" OnClick="ButtonCompletedProjectsClicked">Show Completed Projects</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ButtonClosedIssues" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" OnClick="ButtonClosedIssuesClicked">Show Closed Issues</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

The server controls render the following markup:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <a id="p_lt_ctl01_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_IssuesSettings_userControlElem_ButtonCompletedProjects" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="javascript:__doPostBack('p$lt$ctl01$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl02$IssuesSettings$userControlElem$ButtonCompletedProjects','')">Show Completed Projects</a>
    <a id="p_lt_ctl01_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_IssuesSettings_userControlElem_ButtonClosedIssues" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="javascript:__doPostBack('p$lt$ctl01$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl02$IssuesSettings$userControlElem$ButtonClosedIssues','')">Show Closed Issues</a>
</div>
```

Notice how `_doPostBack` is within the `href` attribute on both anchor elements.  Now, checkout the button.js plugin, you'll see the following lines:

```
// BUTTON DATA-API
// ===============

$(document)
  .on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
    var $btn = $(e.target)
    if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
    Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
    if (!($(e.target).is('input[type="radio"]') || $(e.target).is('input[type="checkbox"]'))) e.preventDefault() // here's the issue
  })
  .on('focus.bs.button.data-api blur.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.btn').toggleClass('focus', /^focus(in)?$/.test(e.type))
  })
```

On line 9 (starting from //BUTTON DATA-API) you'll see `e.preventDefault()` being called at the end of the if statement.  This is going to prevent the anchor tag from performing its default behavior, which would be to call the _doPostBack function.

If you're having this issue and don't need the button plugin, just remove that plugin from your script.  If you do need the button plugin and are having this issue, you'll need to write some logic to handle this.  I modified that if statement on line 9 to check for the '.btn-asp' class first and to proceed with default behavior if that was the case, otherwise it proceeds with the button plugin's logic:

```
if(!($e.target).hasClass(".btn-asp")){
    if (!($(e.target).is('input[type="radio"]') || $(e.target).is('input[type="checkbox"]'))) e.preventDefault() // here's the issue
}
```